# Flattening recursive data structure

Tags: recursion, f#

I have a recursive data stucture in the form of a list of comment threads. Each comment can contain zero or more replies (comments) and each reply can contain zero or more replies. I'm trying to write a function to flatten this list of comment threads, that is that given a list of comment threads, all comments should be returned as "top-level" comments without any replies. I have written a function for this but it does not work, it will return an empty list.

```
type Comment =
  { Text    : string
    Score   : int
    Replies : Comment list }

let flattenReplies ({ Comments = cs }) = 
  let rec flatten st =
    match st with
    | [] ->
      st
    | hd::tl ->
      { hd with Replies = [] }
      :: tl
      |> List.collect (fun c -> flatten c.Replies)
  cs
  |> Seq.toList
  |> flatten
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to implement [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)/[BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) algorithm.
Also, performing this kind of operation may suggest that your initial data structure doesn't fit your needs.

Since your question sounds like a homework problem, I made a simple DFS implementation, surely you can figure out the rest:

```
type Comment =
  { Text    : string
    Replies : Comment list }

let replies = function {Text = _; Replies = rs} -> rs

let flattenReplies (cs : Comment list) = 
  let rec flatten q res = 
    match q with
    | [] -> res
    | h::t -> flatten <| (replies h) @ t <| {h with Replies = []}::res
  flatten cs []
```